# How to stringy a javascript object with a blob as data in it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am recording my webcam with `MediaRecoder` and sending each blob back to sever using `Websocket` as such :

```
 recorder = new MediaRecorder(canvasStream);
            recorder.ondataavailable = e => {
                ws.send(e.data)
            }
```

which works fine, however I want to have more control over the type of message or data that will be send through `Websocket` and therefore I went with the classic

```
ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'REC', data: e.data }))
```

to no avail. I cannot obviously Parse the data back on the server. How can I send a blob to the server while stringifying my message?

Comment: "To no avail" meaning what? It should work. If it didn't, please give us an example of something you had trouble with.

Comment: ...`strigify` ?  Surely there's an error on the browser console for this.

Comment: I think it's a typo here on stack only, and it will be already obvious if its in his IDE,

so I would see what the `ws.send` function does to  `e.data` it could call the `toString`

so try it, `ws.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'REC', data: e.data.toString() }))`

Comment: There was a typo, I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json is a text-based format, it cannot directly include binary data like Blobs. What you can do is to obtain the Blob's `arrayBuffer`, encode it with base64 or hex and send it as text. This will make the upload 1.5-2 times larger though.

Alternatively, you can try a binary transport, like [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/index.html) instead of json.

Comment: I tried messagepack and ran into the same thing with import { unpack, pack } from 'msgpackr';
let serializedAsBuffer = pack(value);
let data = unpack(serializedAsBuffer); Is there like a trick involved into sending blobs?

Comment: @Hypothesis: you have to obtain raw binary data from a blob (`blob.arrayBuffer`) and then give that data to msgpack.